# Jenkins Log to see what is causing a job to fail

Tags: jenkins

I have a job in Jenkins that it testing nunit tests for a project. The Jenkins job fails, although all the unit tests pass.

So on Jenkins it says the build fails - but test results show no failures.

I cannot seem to figure out what is causing the job to fail. Is there some sort of way to see what causes a Jenkins job to be marked as fail? i.e. a detailed log file for a job or something? Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked the *Console Output* for the failed job?

That said, errors in the Console Output can be hard to find, and then harder to understand.  Sometimes I need to log in/remote to the build machine and build the solution, or run the unit tests, manually to see the error in an uncluttered, non-abstracted way (i.e., in the VisualStudio IDE or the NUnit GUI).

Oh, and the [Log Parser Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Log+Parser+Plugin) makes finding errors in Jenkins much easier.

Comment: Hi Zachary... thanks for the feedback. From speaking to others, this seems to be the best approach currently... so for instance, if unit tests are failing... run nunit from the console and see the output from there... Reading the console from within Jenkins is tricky... thanks for the feedback.